# Issues Changing Embedded Youtube video with Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, youtube

I am having issues getting the function to be called.
Whenever I click on the links it seems to ignore the function and just opens the video in youtube full screen mode.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#movies a.youtube").click(function()
         {
            var videoAddress = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#videoArea").html(" ");
            $("#videoArea").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + videoAddress + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

            return false;
        });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML.  I intentionally left the other items without a link as I was just trying to test basic functionality.

```
<div id="videoArea">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mMK9kQtl_i4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>  </iframe>
</div>
        <nav id="movies">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mMK9kQtl_i4?rel=0">Nut Job</a></li>
                <li><a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9G9Ce7e-gws?rel=0">Devil's Due</a></li>
                <li><a class="youtube" href="">Ride Along</a></li>
                <li><a class="youtube" href="">Saving Mr. Banks</a></li>
                <li><a class="youtube" href="">Frozen</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Seems it works well for me. No full-screen mode.

Comment: I just want it to change the video that is embedded and it just won't work for some reason.

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zG42W/), isn't it?

Comment: You script code is before o after the `<div id="videoArea">` code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your jquery code inside `$(function(){});` to give time to DOM to be loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $("#movies a.youtube").click(function()
         {
            var videoAddress = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#videoArea").html(" ");
            $("#videoArea").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + videoAddress + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Agreed, this is the problem. Make sure jQuery loads first (no `$ not defined` errors in the console, then make sure the script doesn't fire until $.ready()

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you.  It seemed like that was the issue I just didn't know how to fix it.